# PHP string.gsub function?

Tags: php, gsub

Iwant to know a function/algorithm like the following:
(this is in Lua)

```
function new_format(str, ...)
  if not str then return '' end

  local replace = {...}
  local count = 1

  local formatted = str:gsub('*', function()
        if replace[count] then
              local rep = replace[count]

              count = count + 1

              if type(rep) == 'Player' then
                    return rep:Name()
              end

              return rep
        end

        return ''
  end)

  return formatted
```

What the code above basically does, is go through the string, and replace a '*', then move on to the next index of the table, and so on.

For example

```
local str = 'Hello *, my name is * :D'
print(new_format(str, 'Stackoverflow', 'bizzy'))
```

the code above would output:
Hello Stackoverflow, my name is bizzy :D

my question is if there is a way to do the same thing in php?

Comment: I tried but i couldn't get them to work the same way the function above works

Comment: Oo so the above is iterating over the string and replacing the same placeholder with various values. `preg_replace_callback` might be what you are after.

Comment: dont mean to bug you, but all the examples look super complex, any idea how this would work for something simple like the example i provided?

Comment: Not with one function I dont. Perhaps https://eval.in/865479?

Comment: thanks, i figured it out :D

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer, not sure I followed what you were doing.